# xterm not inherit environment variables in expect script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, expect

I have a expect script which opens an xterm

I figured out I need to use "exec" in order to open the xterm

```
exec xterm -e '...here is an expect script also..'
```

While I see it is OK to use several command in my script but not in that xterm script.

And later on I found all current environment variables are not set in that xterm

Why? Used bash some much and never meet that problem before. How can I let the xterm inherit all environment variables?

Comment: You'll have to show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Independently from expect there is a rule of thumb for UNIX/Linux:

```
If you want to transfer a variable from parent process to its child process,
you must export this variable in the parent process.
```

You can check, if a variable XYZ has been exported indeed, using command

```
env|grep XYZ
```